# mysql запросы с множественным условием if

Tags: mysql, joomla3

Добрый день. Есть код который получает из базы список районов:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $db->setQuery('SELECT DISTINCT aoguid, offname FROM ADDROBJ_NN WHERE (livestatus = 1 AND aolevel = 3) OR (AOLEVEL = 4 AND LIVESTATUS = 1 AND PARENTGUID = "88cd27e2-6a8a-4421-9718-719a28a0a088") ORDER BY offname');

    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row->aoguid, $row->offname);
    }

return $options;
```

данные выводятся в 1-ый `select`, во 2-ом `select` подгружаются населенные пункты согласно выбранному району. Но есть такая проблема как городские округа. Они должны входить как в районы, так и в города. Как сделать запрос (при условии что я погу дополнять только часть `where` в запросе, чтоб при выбранном к примеру районе `Арзамас`, мне во втором `select` выходили не только нас.пункты входящие в его район, но и сам `г.Арзамас` (таких г.о. штук 10) ??? все данные (районы,города и улицы находятся в одной таблице, парсинг из базы ФИАС). Используется компонент Fabrik. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пробовал так, но не выходит... получилось только выводить насильно везде все г.о. вставкой

```
`aolevel=6 
or aoguid='555e7d61-d9a7-4ba6-9770-6caa8198c483' 
or aoguid='7e42f157-87d6-4111-a406-17432e814723'
```

и т.д.  в поле `Where query`, но это не вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Структура таблицы и образцы данных не указаны в вопросе, так что могу только предположить, что в одном из OR вам нужен подзапрос к той же таблице что то вроде `... OR (parentguid in(select guid from ADDROBJ_NN where parentguid='nnnnn')`

Comment: @Mike, добавил скрин части таблицы, но боюсь, что без знания компонента `Fabrik` для `Joomla` мне ни кто тут не поможет ((( Там нельзя использовать `where` и `and`, надеялся, что при втором `select` можно будет, но нет.

Comment: Хм. но у вас же в примере запрос с where ...

Comment: @Mike, это запрос для первого `select`, как я понимаю в дальнейшем (см. первый скрин) все условия подставляются к этому запросу, а мы можем менять только сам `where`. По этому и написал, что без понимания Fabrik, видимо невозможно мне помочь. За ответ спасибо!